# How to allow the user to select a div(shopping cart) before dropping an item to it

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, shopping-cart, jsfiddle

I am very new to jquery. Presently i am developing a website of shopping cart.Where there are three types of items(item1,item2,item3) and three bags(bag1,bag2,bag3) and one shopping cart such as  bag1 accepts item1,item2,item3 , bag2 accepts item2,item3 and bag3 accepts only item3. 
Which I have developed so far.

Now i want to add additional functionality such as the user should first select any one of the bag(example bag1) and then try dropping items into the bag.Also if they select a bag1 the other two bags dropping functionality should be disable(other bags should not accept any item even if it is  acceptable by that bag) and also reverse if user selects other bags.

PLZ anyone help me.i tried all possible ways.

http://jsfiddle.net/Vwu37/13/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height:100%">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Building a drag-drop shopping cart - jQuery EasyUI Demo</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="height:100%;">
<h2 style="width: 205px">Shopping Cart</h2>
<div class="easyui-panel" fit="true" border="false" style="height:719px; overflow:hidden">

<div class="bag1" style="width: 157px; height: 159px; left: 20px; top: 57px;">
        <img src="images/sb1.jpg" height="150" width="150"/>
 </div>
 <div class="bag2" style="width: 177px; height: 158px; left: 196px; top: 60px;">
        <img src="images/sb2.jpg" height="144" width="173"/>
 </div>
 <div class="bag3" style="width: 203px; height: 150px; left: 400px; top: 62px;">
        <img src="images/sb3.jpg" height="137" width="175"/>
 </div>



    <div class="products1" style="width: 373px; height: 127px; left: 23px; top: 233px;">
        <ul>
         <li>
                <a href="#" class="item1">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="107" width="85"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Feeling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item1">
                    <img src="images/shirt3.gif" height="86" width="81"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Elephant</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item1">
                    <img src="images/shirt4.gif" height="84" width="76"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Stamps</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>



    <br>



<div class="products2" style="width: 343px; height: 146px; left: 30px; top: 377px;">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item2">
                    <img src="images/shoes1.gif" height="93" width="108"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li style="width: 122px; height: 126px">
                <a href="#" class="item2">
                    <img src="images/shoes2.gif" height="84" width="102"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>puma</p>
                        <p>Price:$30</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>

            </ul>
            </div>
             <div class="products3" style="width: 384px; height: 144px; left: 34px; top: 542px;">
        <ul>
         <li>
                <a href="#" class="item3">
                    <img src="images/shirt2.gif" height="107" width="85"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Feeling</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item3">
                    <img src="images/shirt3.gif" height="86" width="81"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Elephant</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#" class="item3">
                    <img src="images/shirt4.gif" height="84" width="76"/>
                    <div>
                        <p>Stamps</p>
                        <p>Price:$25</p>
                    </div>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

        <br><br><br>
    <div class="cart1" style="left: -146px; top: 88px; height: 304px; bottom: -88px; width: 237px">
        <div class="ctitle">Shopping Cart</div>
        <div style="background:#fff">
        <table id="cartcontent1" fitColumns="true" style="width1:300px;height:auto;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th field="name" width=140>Name</th>
                    <th field="quantity" width=60 align="right">Quantity</th>
                    <th field="price" width=60 align="right">Price</th>
                    <th field="remove" width=60 align="right">Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
        </div>
        <div class="ctitle" style="position:absolute;bottom:10px">Drop here to add to cart</div>
    </div>

</div>

    <style type="text/css">
        .bag1{

    position:fixed
}
  .bag2{

    position:fixed
}

  .bag3{

    position:fixed
}

        .products1{
            position:fixed;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .products1 ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .products1 li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .products2{
            position:fixed;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .products2 ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .products2 li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }


.products3{
            position:fixed ;
            height:100%;
            background:#fafafa;
        }
        .products3 ul{
            list-style:none;
            margin:0;
            padding:0px;
        }
        .products3 li{
            display:inline;
            float:left;
            margin:10px;
        }

        .item1{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item1 img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item1 p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

        .item2{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item2 img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item2 p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }

.item3{
            display:block;
            text-decoration:none;
        }
        .item3 img{
            border:1px solid #333;
        }
        .item3 p{
            margin:0;
            font-weight:bold;
            text-align:center;
            color:#c3c3c3;
        }



        .cart1{
            float:right;
            position:relative;
            width:260px;
            height:100%;
            background:#ccc;
            padding:0px 10px;
        }
        .ctitle{
            text-align:center;
            color:#555;
            font-size:18px;
            padding:10px;
        }
      .auto-style3 {
        float: right;
        position: relative;
        width: 260px;
        height: 100%;
        background: #ccc;
        padding: 0px 10px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#cartcontent1').datagrid({
                singleSelect:true,
                showFooter:true
            });


            $('.item1').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });

            $('.item2').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });
             $('.item3').draggable({
                revert:true,
                proxy:'clone',
                onStartDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor = 'not-allowed';
                    $(this).draggable('proxy').css('z-index',10);
                },
                onStopDrag:function(){
                    $(this).draggable('options').cursor='move';
                }
            });


                $('.bag1').droppable({
                accept: '.item1,.item2,.item3',
                 onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                    addProduct(name, parseFloat(price.split('$')[1]));
                }
            });

            $('.bag2').droppable({
                accept: '.item2,.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                   }
            });

            $('.bag3').droppable({
                accept: '.item3',
                onDragEnter:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='auto';
                },
                onDragLeave:function(e,source){
                    $(source).draggable('options').cursor='not-allowed';
                },
                onDrop:function(e,source){
                    var name = $(source).find('p:eq(0)').html();
                    var price = $(source).find('p:eq(1)').html();
                                    }
            });






        });

        function addProduct(name, price){
        var totalQuantity=sumQuantity(data);

    if(totalQuantity < 3){
            var dg = $('#cartcontent1' );
            var data = dg.datagrid('getData');
            function add(){
                for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
                    var row = data.rows[i];
                    if (row.name == name){
                        row.quantity += 1;
                        return;
                    }
                }
                data.total += 1;
                data.rows.push({
                    name:name,
                    quantity:1,
                    price:price
                     remove: '<a href="#" class="remove" onclick="removeProduct(this, event)">X</a>'
                });
            }
            add();
            totalCost += price;
    $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
    $('div.cart1 .total').html('Total: $'+totalCost);
    }else{
        alert('cannot have more than 3 itrems');
    }
}

//new function to sum up all the quantity.
function sumQuantity(data){
   var sum=0;
   for(var i=0; i<data.total; i++){
     sum += data.rows[i].quantity;
   }
   return sum;    
}        



 function removeProduct(el, event) {
    var tr = $(el).closest('tr');
    var name = tr.find('td[field=name]').text();
    var price = tr.find('td[field=price]').text();
    var quantity = tr.find('td[field=quantity]').text();
    for (var i = 0; i < data.total; i++) {
        var row = data.rows[i];
        if (row.name == name) {
            data.rows.splice(i, 1);
            data.total--;
            break;
        }
    }
    totalCost -= price * quantity;
    $('#cartcontent1').datagrid('loadData', data);
    $('div.cart1 .total').html('Total: $' + totalCost);
}

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Create a jsFiddle for this. You will get more answers if you have a test case and don't include so much content. Also... do you *really* style everything inline? If so, I think we may need to have a conversation.

Comment: @screenmutt yes i have styled every thing inline.

Comment: A. That is terrible coding practice. B. Put up a jsFiddle if you want an answer.

Comment: as suggested i edited my question

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer. [jsFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) is a website where you can put up a single page of html/css/js and we can both see and create updates for it. That way we don't ahve to recreate your work locally.

Comment: @Ashhh it's been a long time since you last updated this post. I saw your other related posts and I must say for a starter your code was already pretty advanced. I am struggling too with jQuery and Javascript. Have you found a solution? I guess you could allow user a choice of which bag to be selected? Then based on that input, you could disable `addproduct` function or the entire other `carts` itself.